# Can I limit a SQL user to only stored procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a database and depending on the user I want them to see different things using stored procedures. I don't want them to be able to do direct SQL commands like select. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Do only grant procedure privileges.

Comment: Yes, only grant execute permissions to the procedures you want them to use.

Comment: Things like permissions etc. are **highly dependent** on which RDBMS this is for. Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Tag added. Thanks for all good ways forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the past I have had to give access to a handful of procedures and I would give the login public rights and no database mapping.  This will let them log in but not do anything.  Then I gave select rights to each stored procedure.  I am pretty sure I didnt have to do anything else.

If you have a lot of stored procedures then this article will help you to create a specific role / schema for this.

http://www.patrickkeisler.com/2012/10/grant-execute-permission-on-all-stored.html

Comment: I have got feedback from other source that SQL injections might be a problem with this solution. Can I avoid that problem?

Comment: This is about execution rights.  No relation to sql injection.  That topic is discussed in detail in many other places and regards how you develop your stored procedures not how you give rights to execute them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the user from all groups then just use GRANT on the stored procedures you wish them to have.

```
-- Syntax for SQL Server and Azure SQL Database  

-- Simplified syntax for GRANT  
GRANT { ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }  
      | permission [ ( column [ ,...n ] ) ] [ ,...n ]  
      [ ON [ class :: ] securable ] TO principal [ ,...n ]   
      [ WITH GRANT OPTION ] [ AS principal ]
```

Comment: Why would he remove from'em from "groups"? He should probably create a specific **role** instead.

Comment: I found that's the fastest way to remove all rights. Perhaps not as tidy though

Comment: I have got feedback from other source that SQL injections might be a problem with this solution. Can I avoid that problem?

Comment: SQL injection would only ever be possible if there was dynamic SQL inside the procedure. Even then the attacker would probably need some knowledge of the procedure to make it work.